# itemPress on a Table that was added from controller is not a function

Tags: javascript, xml, sapui5

I am adding a `sap.m.Table` from my controller to the view. I set the itemPress function just like in the view as `itemPress: "onListItemPress"` (in the view it would be `itemPress="onListItemPress"`). However when I press an item in the table and the event is fired, it doesn't 'find' the function, giving me the following `TypeError: I.fFunction.call is not a function`**:**
[image: Error log from Console]
My code:

```
var oTable2 = new sap.m.Table({
    id: "oTable2",
    mode: "SingleSelectMaster",
    keyboardMode: "Navigation",
    itemPress: "onListItemPress", // reeeee
    headerText: this.getTableHeaderText(),
    columns: this.getTableColumns()
});
var oTableContainer = this.getView().byId("idTableContainer");
oTableContainer.addItem(oTable2);
```

How do I reference the function in the controller when setting the control from the controller itself?

Comment: Can't you just do "itemPress: this.onListItemPress,"?

Comment: I tried that, not sure if I tried it without parentheses() tho

Comment: It is without parentheses.

Comment: Wow, yeah it works. That was it? Thank you so much @MatthijsMennens . Do you want to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Hope it helps.

```
itemPress: this.onListItemPress,
```